# How do I fix my python version showing up in terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, anaconda

Even though I have installed Python 3.11 and it shows up on my Applications.
When I go to terminal to check python version it shows this:
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 12:59:45)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin

How do I fix this?

I am on Latest macOS Ventura version.

I've already uninstalled Anaconda but it didn't work in resolving the issue. I want to show the Python 3.11 version showing up on terminal from my Applications.

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix your `PATH`, but your question contains no details, including no indication of which shell you are using. This is a really common FAQ anyway.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have multiple versions of python installed. Your system probably points to `python3.8` as the main `python` version.

In your terminal, type: `python<tab><tab>` (press `<tab>` key twice). It should list every python executable you have. In case it shows `python3.11`, all you need to do to use it is to run `python3.11 your_script.py`.

If you want to know where the `python3.11` binary is, you can do it by running `which python3.11`.

If you want to make `python3.11` the main `python` version in your system, you can do so by creating a sym-link to it in the `/usr/local/bin` directory with these commands:

```bash
# If you already have a python sym-link or binary file there, rename it
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python-

# create sym-link to python3.11
sudo ln -s `which python3.11` /usr/local/bin/python

# check the version
python --version
```

If you try the steps above and it still shows another python version, it could be the order of directories defined in your `$PATH` environment variable. The system looks into those directories to find binary files/commands that you can execute. If `/usr/local/bin` is after `/usr/bin` and there is a `python` executable there, it overrides the previous ones. You can use `which python` to find out which one is overriding it.

Answer (score -1):

I had an extra python variable in my path causing it to use the old version rather than pyenv so removed it from .zshrc and all working now.